# gRPC C# crash (Exception does not bubble up)

Tags: grpc

I am using gRPC version 0.14.0 in C#. It is part of an API provided by a vendor.  When the server is up, all remote invocations work fine.  When the server is not available, the invocation would crash and no exception is being bubble up.

This what my code looks like

```
        try
        {
            Channel channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1", 12122, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
            UtilityService.IUtilityServiceClient stub = UtilityService.NewClient(channel);
            var fiveSecondsInFuture = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5).ToUniversalTime();
            var asynchCall = stub.KeepAlive(new Ping { }, deadline: fiveSecondsInFuture);
            Console.WriteLine(asynchCall.GetStatus());
            var result = asynchCall.ResponseStream.ToListAsync().Result;
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong");
        }
```

What is the best way to handle situations when the server is not available?

Comment: I would suggest that you rewrite the title to include some shorter version of your last sentence, which best asks your actual question.

Comment: This code should not crash, if server is not available, it should throw RpcException with appropriate status code. Please file an issue on https://github.com/grpc/grpc and include more information about your enviroment & platform. Also, we'll need to see more info about the "crash" to be able to help.